# Arrows with different directions

Tags: arrows

I want to drawing two arrows which different directions from 1 edge to 2 edge.

I want to print a and b on the arrows respectively.

[image]

Comment: It's not very clear. Can you illustrate your question with a freehand figure?

Comment: Ok. I am sorry.

Comment: It's clearer, can you modify the image to remove all the unnecessary white part?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\begin{document}
$1\stackrel[b]{a}{\rightleftarrows}2$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyone know how to get this in markdown-embedded equations ?

Comment: In Rmarkdowm, provide the above packages in the YALM header or in a template  and just type the formula in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks. I am using markdown to write documents in VSCode, I found this to work: `$X \underset{txdown}{\stackrel{txup}{\rightleftharpoons}} Y$`

Answer (score 0):

An answer with tikz overlays (1 and 2 are not in the tikz picture but could be)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]\coordinate(#1);\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
{\Huge 1\tikzmark{A}\hspace{50pt}\tikzmark{B}2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[thick,->] ([shift={(0,0.4)}]A)--([shift={(0,0.4)}]B) node[midway, above]{{\large a}};
\draw[thick,<-] ([shift={(0,0.1)}]A)--([shift={(0,.1)}]B) node[midway, below]{{\large b}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear, if you like to have as math expression (as provide [Fran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11604/fran) in his nice answer), or you like to have picture with such content. for the latter is handy package `tikz-cd` (intended for the commutative diagrams):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[r,shift left,"a"]
    &
2 \arrow[l,shift left,"b"]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]